# Why are inline images not visible in Mail on macOS Sierra?

Tags: mac, email, graphics

I'm on Sierra 10.12.3 and Mail wont display inline images. I already Googled for an answer and found a lot of stuff, but no solution so far.

For Yosemite I found [this](http://www.arnan.me/2398/trouble-with-yosemite-mail/) but can't find the option "Automatically detect and maintain account settings" in Sierra. Is it gone?

I already have "Display remote images in html messages" checked.

Answer (score 2):

Did you enable **Load remote content in messages** in Mail Preferences > Viewing ?

[image: Load remote content in messages]

Automatically detect and maintain account settings isn't related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with the current version of macOS. According to the 10.12.4 [update description page](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1911?locale=en_US), it fixes issues with displaying e-mail contents badly. Try updating to that and then see if the issue persists.

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is still present on High Sierra 10.13.6, on my copy at least.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and was looking for an answer, but I found it myself in the process. It turns out my ad blocker, AdGuard, is able to apply its rules to the contents of mail messages too, and apparently the servers that host images for some marketing emails (which I legitimately want to receive) are on one of AdGuard's blacklists. After temporarily disabling AdGuard and re-opening the email message, the images displayed correctly for me. So I figured I'd post this discovery in case it helps anyone else.

tl;dr: Try disabling any ad blocker software you may have installed.

Comment: If you ru an ad-blocker, you may (or not) have an interest in avoiding tracking.  Long ago, spammers discovered a technique for using embedded images to identify which addresses were real so they could sell those addresses to other spammers.  The same technique can be used for tracking.